# What type of adjective is little? Descriptive or quantitative?

Tags: adjectives, quantifiers

Consider the following sentence.

> We should pay **little** attention to little things in life.

What type of adjective is **little** in this sentence? I am confused if it is *descriptive* or *quantitative*.

What about the second *little* in the same sentence? Is it a descriptive adjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

little things = not very important or serious, insignificant, trivial things (descriptive)

little attention = a small amount of attention (quantitative)

pay little attention to sth = not take it seriously

Comment: Can't we take 'little attention' to be 'not serious attention'?

Comment: I think we can, it's both qualitative (careful, close, undivided, special, full attention) and quantitative (little, no, not much attention)